# What's the equivalent of a C# List<byte> in C

Tags: c#, c

If I have C# method that takes in a List as a param such as this

```
private bool ReadResponse(HidDevice device, List<byte> response, int length){
    //do something
}
```

I need to re-write it into C. Would using an `unsigned char *pointer` as the parameter be the correct way of doing that? Here is the current C function signature that I have now. When calling the function I will be passing in `unsigned char data[64]` for the first param.

```
bool ReadReport(unsigned char *response, int length){
    // do something 
}
```

The end use for this being that I need to store all read bytes into a string later on.

Comment: You seem to know how to do this. What is the problem?

Comment: So you definitely can't use C++?

Comment: It's actually a driver being written for Mac. To my knowledge working with C in an Objective-C environment is much easier. I also have little experience with C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it is true that correct type for `byte` would be to use `unsigned char`, or in your case, `unsigned char *response`. With one difference that while in C# you can resize/add new elements to the list on the fly, you can't do that in C; you might need to use `realloc` if that's the case. (Or implement something like a dynamic [vector)](http://www.happybearsoftware.com/implementing-a-dynamic-array.html).

Comment: If I give it a set size say unsigned char buffer[800], I can add to this by using memcpy though right?

Comment: @Stavros_S: I am not sure what you mean, if you allocate array like that you can't change its size anymore. and memcpy is for copying.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got the function with a signature of

```
bool ReadReport(unsigned char *response, int length)
```

you need to call it like

```
ReadReport(data, len);
            ^
            |    //it expects unsigned char *, not unsigned char
```

Comment: @Stavros_S Well, um, so what's the issue?